# C++ Linked list issue

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been working on a little personal project, and have run into a snag. The purpose of the project is to add to my Github, but I have been staring at my code off and on for the last week and cannot find where it goes wrong. The project is a test of my own ability, and my understanding of Linked Lists in C++. Before I go on, here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct payload {
    int ID;
    int x;
    int y;
    string name;
};

struct node {
    node* prev;
    node* next;
    bool isRoot;
    payload data;
};

node* fillStruct(node* tmp);
void print(node* tmp);

int main(void) {
    node* temp;
    node* list;
    node* iterator;

    bool done = false;
    int count = 0;
    char answer;

    do {
        temp = new node();
        temp = fillStruct(temp);
        if (count == 0) {
            list = new node();
            list = temp;
            list->prev = NULL;
            list->next = NULL;
            list->isRoot = true;
        } else {
            list->next = temp;
            temp->prev = list;
            list = new node();
            list = temp;
        }
        count++;

        cout << "Will more elements be added to the list?\n [Y or N]\n";
        cin >> answer;
        switch (answer) {
            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                break;
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                list->next = NULL;
                done = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } while (!done);

    while (list->prev != NULL) {
        list = list->prev;
    }

    int identifier = 100;

    while (1) {
        list->data.ID = identifier;
        identifier++;
        if (list->next == NULL)
            break;
        list = list->next;
    }

    while (list->prev != NULL) {
        list = list->prev;
    }

    while (1) {
        print(list);
        if (list->next == NULL)
            break;
        list = list->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

node* fillStruct(node* tmp) {
    if (!tmp) {
        cerr << "Unauthorized access. Terminating program";
        return tmp;
    }

    cout << "Please enter the X value.\n";
    cin >> tmp->data.x;
    cout << "Please enter the Y value.\n";
    cin >> tmp->data.y;
    cout << "Please enter the data name\n";
    cin >> tmp->data.name;

    return tmp;
}

void print(node* tmp) {
    cout << "Identifier: " << tmp->data.ID << endl;
    cout << "         X: " << tmp->data.x << endl;
    cout << "         Y: " << tmp->data.y << endl;
    cout << "      Name: " << tmp->data.name << endl;
}
```

The code compiles and executes fine. The problem I am having is in the printing phase of the code. It cuts off the last element, and I cannot tell why. The second `while(1)`, as I understand it, should terminate after it prints the final element. If anyone can offer guidance, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance, and as usual, if there's anything I can add to clarify, I will.

Comment: Why do you assume the problem is in the printing phase? How have you proved that other phases are correct, if the printing phase is your only method of examining the structure?

Comment: Add some input and the expected output and the erroneous output, because it works for me in GCC 4.9.0 as far as i can tell.

Comment: I used `cout<<` lines in the initial debugging to mark execution of code segments. The initialization phase works fine, everything also assigns in order. I have isolated the problem down to the loop in question.

Comment: This node `temp = new node();` won't have its `next` field initialized if it's not the root node. So it seems it's a UB further, when you're using this field. As a side node, you're doing some useless object instantiations, like here: first `list = new node();` and then `list = temp;`, which makes no sense.

Comment: @NetVipeC Ok, give me a moment, as GCC 4.9.0 is actually the compiler I'm using as well.

Comment: In the first else branch in the main funcion, an unilitialized list variable is used.

Comment: @Jakub No, it will be initialized by then.

Comment: Ok I have run the code again, and with absolutely no changes it works at this point. Please mark question for deletion (someone who can), as I have evidently wasted my, and your, time. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @BartoszKP. You are right, my fault. I would somehow expect the allocation and initialization outside the do cycle.

Comment: The `next` member in the `} else {` branch is not initialized for `temp` variable (UB here). This could give you intermittent problems when iterating forward the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, it would seem better to keep `list` at the list head, and use a pointer for walking the list.

```
node* list = NULL;
node* ptr = NULL; // tail
do {
    temp = new node();
    temp = fillStruct(temp);
    temp->prev = ptr;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (ptr) {
        ptr->next = temp;
    }
    ptr = temp;
    if (!list) {
        list = ptr;
    }
    count++;

    cout << "Will more elements be added to the list?\n [Y or N]\n";
    cin >> answer;
    switch (answer) {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            break;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            done = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} while (!done);



int identifier = 100;
for (ptr = list; ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
    ptr->data.ID = identifier;
    identifier++;
}

for (ptr = list; ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
    print(list);
}
```